# Sorting array using pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to sort numbers in an array in descending order using pointers. What I have right now just prints the numbers out again without sorting them. How do I get my function to sort the numbers?

```
void new_sort(int nums[], int count) {
 int round; 
 int i;
 int inorder;

  int temp;
  int *num_ptr = nums;

  inorder=0;

  for (round = count -1; (round>0)&&(!inorder); round--) {
     inorder=1;
     for(i=0; i<round; i++) {
        if (*num_ptr<*(num_ptr+1)) {
           inorder = 0;
           temp = *num_ptr;
           *num_ptr = *(num_ptr+1);
           *(num_ptr+1) = temp;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are several different ways you could do it depending on what your design intention was, which we can't determine because there are no comments. For example, what was `num_ptr` supposed to point to?

Comment: It would be worth while to take a look at [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

You are only ever looking at `*num_ptr` and `*(num_ptr+1)`. You should be using `i` or "moving" the pointer as you go.

Answer (score 0):

As **John3136** pointed out, you only ever checking against the first element beeing less than the next one. I assumed you do **not** want to use random array indexing so I went with a solution that uses pointers. I haven't really changed your code that much, I just used pointers instead the counters you used. I tested it with an array, and I think the other parts of your code works fine!

```c
void new_sort(int* const nums, int count) {
    int* const end_ptr = nums + count;
    int* round;
    int inorder;

    int temp;

    inorder = 0;
    int* num_ptr;
    for (round = end_ptr - 1; round != nums && (!inorder); round--) {
        inorder = 1;
        for (num_ptr = nums; num_ptr != round; num_ptr++) {
            if (*num_ptr < *(num_ptr + 1)) {
                inorder = 0;
                temp = *num_ptr;
                *num_ptr = *(num_ptr + 1);
                *(num_ptr + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = { 10, 4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9, 11, 23, 1 };
    new_sort(nums, sizeof(nums) / sizeof(*nums));

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help somewhat.
Cheers!